# Why do I compute diffirent F values in R.

Tags: statistics, regression

So I have some data set and it contains two factor predictors, $X1$ with $3$ levels and $X2$ with $2$ levels, I want to compare the models

$$1+X1$$ vs $$1+X1+X2+X1:X2 $$  that is , the complex model contain interaction.

First of all, ( I am wondering if this is correct reasoning)

I set for example , fit1<- lm(y~1+X1) , and then used anova(fit.1) to read what came up for Sum Sq column and residual row. So would that be SSres of my simple model?

I did the same for the complex model to get what I thought was SSres(complex)

Since the complex model has 6 parameters, the data contains 36 measurements, and the simple model contains 3 parameters, I computed

$$F=\frac{SSres(simple)-SSres(complex)/r}{SSres(complex)/n-p}$$

where $n-p=30$ and $r=3$

This gives me an answer of $F=9.48$

However,

doing fitcomplex<-lm($y~1+X1+X2+X1:X2$)

and then doing drop1(fitcomplex,test='F')

gives me an $F=6.147$

So why do I get different answers for this? Which is the correct one? What is the relation between them?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comments:**

Without seeing the data and the ANOVA tables, it is difficult for me
to give a sharply targeted answer. So here are some comments that *might*
help.

1) Make sure all factor variables are declared as type `factor`.
Otherwise, they will be used as numerical variables (covariates or explanatory variables for regression).

2) It is not a good idea to compare F-ratios in this way. F-distributions with different
degrees of freedom have different shapes. It makes more sense to compare
P-values or R-squared values. If 'R-sq' (not 'R-sq-adj') is smaller for the more complex model, *that* would be surprising; you ought to get a 'better fit' to
the more complex model.

3) If you don't get an answer on this site that is useful, you might want to
try our sister site 'cross-validated' which is often more attuned to issues
in applied statistics. But if you do so, try to give them more details to work  with than you have given here.